# Weird C++ bug in Linux/Unix?

Tags: c++

So I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct helloworld {
    char name[1];
};

main() {
    struct helloworld test[2];
    strcpy(test[0].name, "No .1");
    strcpy(test[1].name, "No .2");
    for (int integer = 0; integer < 2; integer++) {
    cout << test[integer].name << endl;
    }
}
```

and I save it to a file called test.cpp. To compile the file, I do

```
g++ -o main test.cpp
```

Then when I run ./main this is the output I get

```
NNo .2
No .2
```

This is the expected output

```
No .1
No .2
```

Any ideas of why I am getting this error how to fix this bug?

Comment: You are writing in memory you don't own. Use `strncpy`.

Comment: You've defined `name` as a single character array, and you're putting more than a single char into it. IOW, you've overrun the bounds of the array, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Undefined behavior / buffer overrun.  You allocate an array of 1 character, but you copy 6 characters (nul terminator inclusive) to the array.  Look out for Nasal Demons!

Comment: Alright, thank you Axalo. I found the answer in the article. You too lared.

Comment: @lared `strncpy` is just as easy to misuse as `strcpy`. If you have to use c strings, `sscanf` is more powerful, easier to use, and safer than `strncpy`/`strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying too many characters into a char array of size 1.  Make your `char name[1]` bigger (e.g. 10 or so for this example).

Better yet, use `std::string` instead.